# How to hide all opened marker popups in mapbox-gl?

Tags: mapbox-gl

I can't find the way to hide all opened marker popups  or even check marker popup state.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to close all popups programmatically in mapbox gl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40859195/how-to-close-all-popups-programmatically-in-mapbox-gl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think `getPopup().isOpen()` would allow you to check state, and `getPopup().remove()`(ran while iterating over all of your stored markers in some array) would accomplish what you need here.