# How to disable "close all popups" in MapBox?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Not too long ago, people had a really hard time getting all popups to close on map click in mapbox ([How to close all popups programmatically in mapbox gl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40859195/how-to-close-all-popups-programmatically-in-mapbox-gl)).

They've since changed this to the default behavior, which is nice, but does not suit my current project.

**How does one NOT have all popups close on click out?**

And once that is disabled:

**How does one *programmatically* close selected popups on click out?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```js
const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ closeOnClick: false });

map.on('click', () => popup.remove());
```

Answer (score 0):

i am working on reactJS just add closeOnClick attribute to false in Popup component example below

```
<Popup
        longitude={Number(longitude)}
        latitude={Number(latitude)}
        closeOnClick={false}
      >
<!--modal content-->
</Popup>
```